# Is there any way to improve this loop?

Tags: python, dataframe, loops

There are some inputs and they can be strings inside a list or None

I need to add df.col_2 to df.col_1 if the input matches its respective column

i.e.:

```
if df.INPUT_1.iloc[0] in input_1:
        df.col_1.iloc[0] = df.col_1.iloc[0] + df.col_2.iloc[0]
```

I have the following code that can do the work for two inputs:

```
if input_1 == None and input_2 == None:
    for i in range(len(df)):
        df.col_1.iloc[i] = df.col_1.iloc[i] + df.col_2.iloc[i]
elif input_1 != None and input_2 == None:
    for i in range(len(df)):
        if (df.INPUT_1.iloc[i] in input_1):
            df.col_1.iloc[i] = df.col_1.iloc[i] + df.col_2.iloc[i]
elif input_1 == None and input_2 != None:
    for i in range(len(df)):
        if (df.INPUT_2.iloc[i] in input_2):
            df.col_1.iloc[i] = df.col_1.iloc[i] + df.col_2.iloc[i]
elif input_1 != None and input_2 != None:
    for i in range(len(df)):
        if (df.INPUT_1.iloc[i] in input_1) and (df.INPUT_2.iloc[i] in input_2):
            df.col_1.iloc[i] = df.col_1.iloc[i] + df.col_2.iloc[i]
```

But i'm after a more pythonic way so i don't have to write a extensive code if i need to check another input

Comment: You could use ```all()``` i.e. ```if all(input == None for input in input_list)```. Up to you to define the ```input_list```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    if ((not input_1 or df.INPUT_1.iloc[i] in input_1) and 
        (not input_2 or df.INPUT_2.iloc[i] in input_2)):
        df.col_1.iloc[i] += df.col_2.iloc[i]
```

Thus, inverting so that the `for` loop is the outer structure and then test for the different contstraints individually for each value. Depending on the the data, it may be a bit less efficient, but it is probably easier to grasp.

**Edit:**

Or to align more with the original code:

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    if ((input_1 is not None or df.INPUT_1.iloc[i] in input_1) and 
        (input_2 is not None or df.INPUT_2.iloc[i] in input_2)):
        df.col_1.iloc[i] += df.col_2.iloc[i]
```

As pointed out by @MoritzVetter below, my un-edited answer treats an empty list differently than the original code. The solution I presented will ignore empty lists while the original code will assume them to be lists in which to look for inputs. The reason I made this choice was because I believed this to be the intention of the original code, but of course I do not know this for sure.

If empty lists are to be considered as valid, it should be noted, as done in the comment, a better way to compare with `None` is to use the `var is not None` rather than `var != None`. It may be a minor point, but it makes the code a bit more "Pythonic" and there are actually cases in where the results may be different (with overloaded tests for equality).

Comment: Maybe `input_1 is not None or...` depending on how to treat empty lists.

Comment: @MoritzVetter Absolutely, I considred writing it like that, to better align with the original code, and I should probably have commented on the choice I made. I willl update my answer with a short discussion about this. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

I'd simply do something like this:

```py
def check_valid(entry, sequence):
    if sequence is None: 
        return true

    return entry in sequence


for i in range(len(df)):
    if check_valid(df.INPUT_1.iloc[i], input_1) and check_valid(df.INPUT_1.iloc[i], input_2):
        df.col_1.iloc[i] = df.col_1.iloc[i] + df.col_2.iloc[i]

# For n inputs
CHECK_THOSE = (
  (df.INPUT_1.iloc, input_1),
  (df.INPUT_2.iloc, input_2),
  # ...
)

for i in range(len(df)):
    if all(check_valid(entry, sequence) for entry, sequence in CHECK_THOSE):
        df.col_1.iloc[i] = df.col_1.iloc[i] + df.col_2.iloc[i]
```